# Passing strings between forms while both forms are are being shown on screen

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015

Hello to stackoveflow community members.!

I am reading threads from stackoverflow from past 6 months and which was really helpful for me. I never get stuck to anything where i need to write my own question here.
Currently i am working on visual studio 2015 with window based .net application. 
I am having multiple forms in my application. I am loading a form into another form through panel control. 
Say i have a form1 which is main form and form2 which i have opened main form using panel control.
 When i am opening my form1 as startup form the data transfer is taking place. But when i am using another form say form3 for login page as startup the data transfer is not working between form1 and form2. 
Could some please help.!!

Please find example code as below.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6p1o.png)
Number of Forms - 3,
Form3 as Login Form,
Form1 as Main Form,
Form2 as Entry Form,

Code for Form3-==========

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim form1 As New Form1
        form1.Show()
        Me.Hide()
 End Sub
```

Code for Form1-===========

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        RichTextBox1.Text = "Hello"
    End Sub
    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Dim f As Form
        f = Form2
        f.TopLevel = False
        f.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal
        f.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None
        Me.Panel1.Controls.Add(f)
        f.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
        f.Show()
    End Sub
```

Code for Form2-=========

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Form1.RichTextBox1.Text = Me.TextBox1.Text
    End Sub
```

Comment: Don't create new instances of forms. Use the default `Form1`.That should be the only difference between C Sharp and vb.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by 'Preciousbetine', i have removed new instance for form1. Application is working as desired.
Thank you so Much!!!

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
            Form1.Show()
            Me.Hide()
     End Sub
```